# Normal line: $-5$ or $\frac{1}{5}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Find the equation of the normal line to the graph of $f$, $f(x) = \ln(x + 1)$, so that the normal line is parallel to the line $y = −5x + 101$.

Here's the formula for finding normal line:
$y - y_{0} = \frac{-1}{f'(x_{0})}(x-x_{0})$

I am simply wondering: when considering the coefficient $\frac{-1}{f'(x_{0})}$, should I treat it as $-5$ or $\frac{1}{5}$? $-5$ seemed obvious to me, because it's parallel to $y=-5x+101$, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

Thanks!

Comment: You are right..

Comment: You’re correct. The slope must match up with the slope of the line if it’s parallel.

Comment: I do have a bonus question. Basically tangent line parallel to some line is basically a normal line perpendicullar to that line? And vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $-5$ is correct - parallel lines do not intersect, and this can only happen if they have the same slope / gradient. It would be $\frac15$ if you were asked to find a line that is *perpendicular* to the line with slope $-5$.

Comment: I do have a bonus question. Basically tangent line parallel to some line is basically a normal line perpendicullar to that line? And vice-versa.

Comment: @weno I don't think that's right (if I am understanding correctly). A **tangent** line to some curve means a line that is **parallel** to that curve. A **normal** line is a line that is **perpendicular** to the curve. So these two things are related in this way, and are each perpendicular to each other. Does that answer what you were asking?